# How to add netbeans platform for compiling iReport sources?

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport, netbeans-platform

I need to customize iReport sources.. (not creating plugin)

Currently i am using iReport 3.7.2 and netbeans 6.5.1 ide. I downloaded the netbeans platform 6.0.1 and followed the procedures as shown in the jaspersoft link on how to compile iReport sources.

But when i tried to compile the sources. I am getting errors like libs-xerces-jar is of incompatible specification version. And if i replace the jar new version of that jar in the NetBeans platform 6.0.1-200801291616 folder  I am getting org-netbeans-awt.jar is of incompatiable specification version. and the same incompatiable specification version error is throwing for other jars in the netbeans platform folder.

Can anyone help me in this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my problem solved. I used Netbeans 6.8 and add the netbeans platform 6.5.1 Build 200903060201. Now i am able to compile the sources

Answer (score 0):

Well, try using Netbeans 6.8. 
6.5 and 6.0 are quite old right now.